# Scala - Mutable Map

Tags: scala, csv, dictionary, mutable

Is there any way to create mutable map in scala by using variables?
I am reading a csv file with source.fromFile("abc.csv").getlines. I want 1st 2 columns of this file to be the key and rest as values. I want to do the same with 2nd file so I can compare these 2 files based on the key and get the difference.
eg: file abc.csv is as below:
Company,Empid,Name
1,10,Abc
1,11,PQR
2,10,XYZ

I want o/p as Map(110->Abc,111->PQR, 210->XYZ)

I tried to achieve it by:

```
var keymap = collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()
val content = Source.fromFile("abc.csv").getLines;
val data = content.drop(1); //to remove header
for (line <-data){   
    val x = line.substring(0,1).toInt;
    val y = line.substring(2,4).toInt;
    var key = (x*100) + y;
    var value = line.substring(9);
    var keymap += (key,value);
}
```

But it gives error as -
    :60: error: type mismatch;
    found   : Int
    required: (Int, String)
                  keymap += (key,value)
                             ^

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no need of mutable map to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If keymap is mutable, why are you taking it as var, take it as val.Try this.

```
scala> val tasks = mutable.Map[Int,String]()
tasks: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()
scala> tasks += (1,"Book a movie ticket")
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: (Int, String)
       tasks += (1,"Book a movie ticket")
scala> tasks += (1 -> "Book a movie ticket")
res13: tasks.type = Map(2 -> " movie ticket", 1 -> Book a movie ticket)
```

So, you have to change this

```
keymap += (key-> value)
```

Comment: Nope its still not working. i also removed var/val from keymap += (key,value) as I had already declared keymap at first line. But still not working.

Comment: if i change to val as you suggested it gives error  '=' expected but ';' found.
           val keymap += (key,value);
  if i remove var/val it gives error gives the same error mentioned in my 1st question.

Comment: Oops i made a mistake, yes you just don't need to declare it again. You just have to give array between key and value. keymap += (key-> value)